# App capability removed after pubblication

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

When I test my app on my device, by deploying it with Visual Studio directly from my pc to my phone, ad is showing. Then I published my app, and there the ad is not showing.

After some research, I found that my to show my ad correctly my app should have  `ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT` in WMAppManifest file. I noticed, by watching my app's details inside my developer dashboard, that that id_cap is being removed after publishing the app!

I'm not the only, one but I didn't find an answer.

Some posts:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a172dcb6-7e31-45a1-82f1-44bcd8aeac73/my-app-needs-idcapwebbrowsercomponent-but-marketplace-says-not?forum=wpsubmit

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6e5c635d-fcb4-4156-97fe-c5153088bb91/ads-are-not-showing-im-my-published-app-they-worked-during-development-whats-up-with-that?forum=wpdevelop

Note that I'm working with XNA-Silverlight and using the `DrawableAd` associated with `AdComponent`.

I really don't know how to handle this problem. Maybe can I add the capability programmatically?

** EDIT **

I aknowledged that the manifest file is just used while debugging, when you submit an app, it's capababilities are recognized automatically. Here is the problem. I run the StoreKitTeste in Visual Studio as shown here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg180730(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UsingtheMarketplaceTestKittoDetermineApplicationCapabilitiesforWindowsPhoneOS71Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg180730%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_UsingtheMarketplaceTestKittoDetermineApplicationCapabilitiesforWindowsPhoneOS71Applications)

and in fact it doesn't recognize `ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT`. How can I make him see that I need it?

** EDIT 2 ***

I found here the same problem http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/be-careful-when-submitting-for-windows-phone-marketplace-an-app-that-uses-capturesource-class

It is related to microphone capability, how can I do the same with Webbrowsercomponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added:  `WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();` somewhere and it recognized its capability.

Comment: While this isn't THE answer, it's definitely a great work-around until Microsoft fixes this...